# Theming Block Contents in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I can change the overall layout of a block editing the `block.tpl.php` file. I can modify the way `subject` looks, but what I want to take control over `contents` of the block which is accessible by single line of code:

```
<?php print $content ?>
```

Now, How can I theme **contents** of the block, i.e. list items etc?

*If I've failed to clarify myself, please mention it in your comments. Thanks :)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before blocks get to the theme layer, they can be altered. Blocks are represented as "render arrays", which means you can manipulate them with the [Render API](http://drupal.org/node/930760).

You can use [`hook_block_view_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7) to change the contents of a block.

Any module or theme can implement this hook. For example, a theme named YOURTHEME would have code like this:

```
function YOURTHEME_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
  // Remove the contextual links on all blocks that provide them.
  if (is_array($data['content']) && isset($data['content']['#contextual_links'])) {
    unset($data['content']['#contextual_links']);
  }
  // Add a theme wrapper function defined by the current module to all blocks
  // provided by the "somemodule" module.
  if (is_array($data['content']) && $block->module == 'somemodule') {
    $data['content']['#theme_wrappers'][] = 'mymodule_special_block';
  }
}
```

Or, if you know in advance the module and delta you'd like to alter, you can use [`hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter/7) like this:

```
function YOURTHEME_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter(&$data, $block) {
  // This code will only run for a specific block. For example, if MODULE_DELTA
  // in the function definition above is set to "mymodule_somedelta", the code
  // will only run on the "somedelta" block provided by the "mymodule" module.

  // Change the title of the "somedelta" block provided by the "mymodule"
  // module.
  $data['subject'] = t('New title of the block');
}
```

Comment: Also, is it possible to customize the look & feel by editing some `.tpl.php` file? I'm having a `menu` to be displayed in the `block`

Comment: I figured out editing `modules/system/system.menus.css` may solve my problem. What is the D7 way to do so? @timplunkett

Answer (score 1):

You can use Views to generate a block which you can exactly theme the way you want.

Comment: Also a good Idea... but can it be desirable in all cases?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you cannot. `$content` is the minimal piece of information known to the block module.

Comment: This is a broad question, like how can I style list items with CSS. You need to be more specific: What list items? What module creates them or are they user created?

Comment: menu modules @ipwa